# Importing TypeScript Failed

Tags: typescript, import, dao

Asked to make a laboratory and an import error occurred

//dao.ts file

```
    import * as fs from "fs";
    const file = fs.readFileSync("foo.txt", "utf8");
    console.log(file);
```

I write "node dao.ts" in console and i have error:

```
    import * as fs from "fs";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: try tsc nao.ts and later node dao.js

Comment: @0210vidit sanks, but when i used any import i have error

**
```
import * as mongo from "mongodb";  
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```
**